# Is there a better approach to "grab" every database row as one unique variable for it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller I need to pick all of these rows and doing like this currently:

```
$policy1 = GlobalVariable::findOrFail(1);
$policy2 = GlobalVariable::findOrFail(2);
$policy3 = GlobalVariable::findOrFail(3);
$policy4 = GlobalVariable::findOrFail(4);
```

Is there a better approach to grab these four rows and assign variable row key names for them?

Comment: Since you're using an ORM anyway, you should do [column_name IN list_of_values query](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/in.php), translate that to laravel from google

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: it would be easier to have them as an array or collection I would think ... `$policies = GlobalVariable::findOrFail([1, 2, 3, 4])->keyBy('id'); ... $policies[1];`